# How to load specific entries into userform from worksheet (and browse between them)?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, populate

My worksheet has 2 user forms. One to enter new data into sheet and another to browse through specific entries, only showing a few pieces for the user to confirm they have the right entry to download to PDF.

[image: Data form]

I need the 2nd userform (above) to load the latest entry where the value in column (K) is 'yes'. And then display the `txtdossier` (D), `txtdate` (A), and `txtcontainer` number (C). And then either manually input a `txtDossier` number and have the related info show, or be able to browse through the entries with prev/next.

What is the best way to not only show an entry when condition in column K is met, but also to adjust as new entries are added to the sheet.

The only way I know how to do it now is to manually add every new entry into the code.

I.e. 
`UserForm2.txtDossier.Text = CStr(Range("c5").Value)`

Please add comments when possible, my understanding of VBA is below basic still.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.txtDate.Enabled = False
Me.txtDate.BackColor = RGB(224, 224, 224)
Me.txtContainer.Enabled = False
Me.txtContainer.BackColor = RGB(224, 224, 224)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Doss As String
Dim Datum As String
Dim Container As String
Dim FaseJa As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Meting Fase 2 lijst")

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by latest? The last entry? I.e. the last row? Or is there a column with dates or something?

Comment: Yes, in the userform1 users can add new entries. So when they do that, I want them to be able to immediately go back to this userform it to download it as PDF. The sheet saves the date (and time) with `.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Now`. The Date can be found in Column A.

Comment: I dont really know how to answer this question without simply writing the code for you. But what I would do is probably use .find to look for a yes in column K, with xlprevious to find the last row with a yes. and then just assign the relevant values like so `txtDossier = ws.Range("D" & LastRowWithAYes)` etc. Maybe match works better or maybe I would work with a public variable and an array if your data is super huge. If you try some stuff and run into errors I`ll be happy to help but right now i would just have to write it

Answer (score 0):

This code won't solve your problem, but is too long to fit in a comment.

Assuming your form is called `UserForm2` and contains these controls:  `txtDossier`, `txtDate` and `txtContainer` then you can add the following code to a normal module.

As @Czeskleba said - to solve your problem we'd have to write the code for you, which isn't what this site is about.  Have a look at [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to track down the records you're looking for.  [Excel Macro Mastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/) also has good explanations on how to use it.

```
Public Sub Test()

    'Open first instance of form.

    Dim frm As UserForm2
    Set frm = New UserForm2

    With frm
        .Caption = "First Displayed Form"
        .txtDossier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
        With .txtDate
            .Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")
            .Enabled = False
        End With
        .txtContainer = "Some data in here"
        .Show
    End With

    'Open second instance of form.
    'If forms ShowModal property is set to TRUE then this code will run after first form is (manually) closed.
    'If ShowModal is set to FALSE then two forms will appear.

    Dim frm2 As UserForm2
    Set frm2 = New UserForm2

    With frm2
        With .txtDossier
            .BackColor = RGB(224, 224, 224)
        End With
        .Caption = "Second Displayed Form"
        .txtDate = Format(DateSerial(2019, 12, 25), "ddd dd-mmm-yy")
        .txtContainer.Enabled = False
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```